# Is It necessary to know reactjs to learn react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am starting to learn to build apps using react-native and curious about about one question that whether i should learn react-js before learning react native.... please help...

Comment: It is still react, if you learn one, you know the other and vice versa

Comment: Yes, React Native uses React.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on native from start of my carrer, you need knowledge of react.
All you need to know is JSX,React-life cycles and redux(state management if necessary). its easy to start with and community support is amazing.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to learn React.js, if you have basic JavaScript knowledge. 
you can learn React.js as you advance in React-native.